# How to completely get rid of the copy-mode in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I find the copy-mode in `tmux` rather annoying; I have to frequently enter and quit it.

Is it possible to make the `tmux` windows work like standard terminals? I want to scroll, copy and paste anytime in place.